# how to hist graph by using matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to plot probability and compare with theoretical value by using MATLAB.

The question is that

1. Roll one dice
2. If the number is 1 -> win , else -> lose
3. Roll N times
4. How many times to roll the dice to obtain the winning probability close to the theoretical value 1/6?

I know the win probability is p=1/6, else p=5/6, 
And I think the guideline to make code. Set n = 0, generate one of the integers 1~6 uniformly, Add a win if 1 was generated and add a loss otherwise, n++, go back to 1 if n

Can you please what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
N=100;

win=0;
lose=0;
a=randi([1 6],1,1);

n=0;
p=0;

while n<N
  if a==1
    p=p+1/6;
  else
    p=p+5/6;
  end if
end while

hist(N,p);
```

Comment: the last sentence is n<N, and please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you intend with `p=p+1/6`? Your description says to "add a win", which would be `win=win+1`, no? Also, you do `while n<N`, but neither `n` nor `N` change inside the loop, so the condition never changes.

Comment: Also you should either generate `N` random integers at once or put `a=randi([1 6],1,1)` inside your while loop (now you're trying to compare N time the same value which make no sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am not interpreting your question correctly, but I believe you are asking how big N has to be to get a probability near 1/6. I would probably create a matrix `a`. As I show below, the first column of `a` is 10000 random values from 1:6. The second column of `a` is equal to 1 if the corresponding value in column one is equal to 1 otherwise zero.

The third column is the probability through "kth" row of the data. That is `a(100,3)` is the number of times a 1 was rolled in the first 100 tries divided by the number of tries which is the probability of success.

From there, rather than a histogram i would simply plot `a(:,3)` and compare to 1/6 as I did with the plot command.

```
N=10000;

a=randi([1 6],N,1);
a(:,2) = a(:,1) == 1;
a(:,3) = cumsum(a(:,2)) ./ (1:N)';

plot(1:N, a(:,3))
hold on 
plot([1,N], [1/6, 1/6], "Color","r")
```

As an aside, within MATLAB I am not familiar with

```
end if
end while
```

I would expect both lines of code to be just `end`.

Comment: Your loop can be replaced with something like `cumsum(a(:,2)) ./ (1:N).'`. And instead of three columns, I'd use three different variables, it would make the code look cleaner and simpler.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ... code improved per your comment regarding loop - thank you.